# scrolling on view highlighting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to scroll through textarea fields in the view using a next button on top of the keyboard, when it shifts to the last textarea field it's scrolling downwards and hiding behind the keyboard.

code:

```
 (CGRect)getObjectRectFromRoot {

    int yOffset = 0;

   yOffset += self.view.frame.origin.y;

   UIView* suView = self.view.superview;

    while (suView) {
       yOffset += suView.frame.origin.y;
        suView = suView.superview;
    }

    CGRect r;
    r.size.width = 700;
    r.size.height = 700;
    r.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    r.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
    r.origin.x = 0;
    r.origin.y = yOffset;

    return r;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing this code in the two delegate methods of your textField will do what you want. Here is the ***textFieldDidBeginEditing***:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect textFieldRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
CGFloat numerator =
midline - viewRect.origin.y
- MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat denominator =
(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
* viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

if (heightFraction < 0.0)
{
    heightFraction = 0.0;
}
else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
{
    heightFraction = 1.0;
}

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}
else
{
    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}

CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And here is the ***textFieldDidEndEditing:***

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
[self textFieldShouldReturn:textField];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

If you want it for the buttons you can just setup an ***IBAction*** with the above code.

The code can also be used with any other type of action or view you would like!